# How To Create Custom Alert Dialog programmatically based on device width and height in xamarin android?

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, dialog, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I have created Custom Alert Dialog using XmL where my

```
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
```

but it looks clumsy so How To Create Custom Alert Dialog programmatically based on device width and height in xamarin android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `Height` and `Width` of Screen using below code

```
var metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
var windowManager = this.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService) as IWindowManager;
windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);

var height = metrics.HeightPixels;
var width = metrics.WidthPixels;
```

and also to set the `AlertDialog` width and height programatically like below way

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
AlertDialog alert;
alert = builder.Create();
alert.Window.SetLayout(width - 100, height - 100);
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: if we use builder.SetIcon() ...image won't be placed centre?